# Turn * into thin space for clearer math spacing

Tags: spacing, catcodes

In a formula, the space between variables often corresponds implicitly to a multiplication operator. I find LaTeX's default spacing not so readable: symbols are too close to each other, and I would like to see a bit more space between them, automatically (i.e. without manually inserting it). Admittedly, it is a matter of taste, but also imho of legibility. As MWE:

```
$a x + b$ vs $a \hspace{0.07em} x + b$ and $y dx$ vs $y \hspace{0.07em} dx$
```

[image: ax+b and y dx with standard and extra spacing]

Globally changing the math spacing might (i) be a bit complicated and (ii) mess up the fine tuned LaTeX compilation. But [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/) offers to do it by deciding that the symbol `*` should be typeset as a (thin) space. That way, one preserves the meaning in the source (a multiplication), which is still readable ( `x * y` vs `x \, y`), while obtaining a visually pleasing output.
I am not familiar with `catcode`, but could it be used to replace all `*` with a predetermined space? (I can do without the `*` symbol anyway.) I am aware of the previous [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28936/extra-space-between-number-and-variable-in-math-mode) on this topic, but the answers have failed to convince me, and I would like to go ahead.

Comment: There is no need to space `ax+b`; actually I consider such spacing wrong.

Comment: @egreg I have seen your point, and I respect it. There are strong arguments in its favor. Nevertheless, I beg to differ, and wish to experiment something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\*\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\,}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\*="8000 }
```

But, regarding the differential, I would use a macro

```
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!d}
```

So you would write

```
$a x + b$ vs $a * x + b$ and $y dx$ vs $y \dif x$
```

Comment: Beat me here by a hair. +1 :)

Comment: @SeanAllred and me by half that:-)

Comment: Regarding your macro, when possible, I like to use `\newcommand\d[1]{\,d#1}`, myself. Keeps the code very readable (`\int f(x) \d x`). My macro is very naive, though :)

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't really mind renewing commands, and I use myself `\d` too (although with a different definition `\renewcommand*\d{\mathop{}\!d}`). If you really want it to have an argument `\renewcommand*\d[1]{\mathop{}\!d#1}` but you should take care of `^{<superscripts>}`.

Comment: @Manuel Superscripts... good point :)

Comment: +1 for the solution... although it would be nice a bit of comments for the non-magic crowd out there :-)... ¿`\lowercase`?

Comment: @Rmano Just searching for the `\lowercase` trick gives you [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156759/21930) :)

Comment: @SeanAllred http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250674/how-to-get-rid-of-c-cedilla-in-math-mode/250676#comment597358_250676 I would personally use the version without arguments, and, if you prefer, use `\d{x}` or `\d^{2}{x}`, which would still give the correct spacing.

Comment: @Manuel thanks --- it seems it's almost time, (censored) years after, to reread the TeXbook...

Comment: I use this, borrowed from an answer on this site: `\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}}`

Comment: @Bernard This is equivalent to, but more complicated than, `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`; *don't* do `\renewcommand{\d}`, you'll regret it, once or later.

Comment: @Bernard It's *exactly* the same. But that solution is over difficult: (1) `\kern0pt` is there just so `\mathop{..}` doesn't vcenter its argument; (2) `{}` is there just to add an ordinary atom after the `\mathop`. With the other definition (1) you don't have to worry of the vcentering, because the argument is empty; and (2) you don't need to add an atom because the `d` is itself an ord atom (or the `\mathrm{d}`, which is the same).

Comment: @egreg: I know it's dangerous, but I also use `\diffp` from the `esdiff` package (from time to time only, as I'm an algebraist…), which is very close. I know I should think of a solution :o)

Comment: @Manuel: Doesn't `\mathop` add some space between what's before and the `d`? This a code I do not fully understand, I must say. Your explanations shed some light on it.

Comment: @Bernard Which is removed by `\!` exactly the same as your solution.

Comment: @Manuel:??? I thought `\!` was there to remove the extra spacing (due to `\mathop`) between the `d` and what follows.

Comment: @Bernard Well not exactly (but yeah, I did not explain correctly) the space is between `\mathop` and the next ord atom. In your definition the `d` is inside `\mathop` so, as you say, `\!` is there to remove the space between the `d` and the following `{}` (ord atom). (I will remove all this comments of the discussion)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the comments. Though the issue of the differential command is a bit off-topic (I meant it only as an example), it is interesting _per se_. To keep it connected to the original, I noticed that defining d as a `\mathop` seems to insert an extra space _in front_ which defeats the original purpose. Try `y \diff x` and `y*\diff x`; the former is good enough, while the latter is now too "spaced". By the way, I would change in @Manuel's definition `\,` into `\hspace{0.07em}` (or whatever looks best), since the classical thin space is a bit too large for my taste.

Comment: @PascalRomon Well, the main idea of using a `\diff` command is that you don't have to worry about spacing, it's taken care by itself. So `*` there wouldn't be necessary. I mean `\int f(x) \dif x` is readable enough.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in my answer to [Automatic spacing of symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203633/automatic-spacing-of-symbols/204089) . Here is it again:

```
\mathcode`\*="8000
{\catcode`\*=\active
\gdef*{\mathclose{}\,\mathopen{}}}
```

Compare

```
$a*b$ 
$a b$ 
$a\,b$
$a*\cos b$
$a \cos b$
$a\,\cos b$
```

The `\mathopen{}` avoids inserting two thin spaces if `*` is in front of a `\mathop`.

[image]

Comment: All right I'm convinced. I had not thought that a `\mathop` would tamper with the above solution, but it does, and your solution smartly prevents this. I'll stick with my preferred length though: `\hspace{0.07em}`.